# How to config permission for `getDownloadURL()` from firebase-admin to run locally with firebase emulator?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I'm calling the [`getDownloadURL(fileRef)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#shareable_urls) using the admin package inside a cloud function.

```
import admin, { firestore } from "firebase-admin";
import { getStorage, getDownloadURL } from "firebase-admin/storage";

admin.initializeApp();

myFunc(filePath) {
  // `filePath` is a path to an image file in the firebase Storage.
  // I have enabled the storage emulator as well.
  const file = getStorage().bucket().file(filePath);

  // This throws error when running in emulator only
  const fileUri = await getDownloadURL(file);
  
  console.log(fileUri);
}
```

It works in deployed instances but running in a local emulator throws permission-denied error.

I've tried doing

```
// I am using the file of the current connected project.
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key.json"

firebase emulators:start
```

but getting the same result. [Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional)

How to properly configure it?
I am also unsure which credential file I should be using to enable access to the emulator's storage service.

Comment: Can you share you CF code?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec hey I've added in the post

Comment: it is an open issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2344

What you can do as a risky workaround is to set the security rule 
allow read: if true; 
Unless you do other logic in security rules for your app.

Don't forget to remove it for deployment.